# Bash script and Crontab is not working as expected

Tags: bash, cron

I want to schedule cron job for my file webScraping.py. When I execute manually everything work perfectly.

```
#!/bin/bash

SCRIPT_DIR=$( cd -- "$( dirname -- "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" &> /dev/null && pwd )
datetime="$(gdate +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%3N')"

LOG_FILE=webScraping.log
LOG_FORMAT="${datetime} | INFO | $(BASENAME "$0"):${FUNCNAME[0]}:${LINENO} -"

exec >> $LOG_FILE 2>&1

echo "${LOG_FORMAT} Running the bash script"

echo "${LOG_FORMAT} The script bash you are running has :"
echo "${LOG_FORMAT} basename: [$(BASENAME "$0")]"
echo "${LOG_FORMAT} pwd : ['$SCRIPT_DIR']"

export TZ="Europe/Paris"

(crontab -l ; echo "30 23 * * * $SCRIPT_DIR/webScraping.py") | crontab -

python3 $SCRIPT_DIR/webScraping.py >> $PWD/$LOG_FILE 2>&1

echo "${LOG_FORMAT} The script bash was successfully executed"
```

When I  run crontab -l, it display it :

`30 23 * * * /Users/kevin/PycharmProjects/Projects2024/nov23_continu_mlops_meteo/src/data/webScraping.py`

I don't know where is the issue

This is my LOG_FILE=webScraping.log, it only show when the script is manually executed but not at 23:30 when the Cron job should run

```
2024-03-18 23:26:07.489 | INFO | runWebScraping.sh::7 - Running the bash script
2024-03-18 23:26:07.489 | INFO | runWebScraping.sh::7 - The script bash you are running has :
2024-03-18 23:26:07.489 | INFO | runWebScraping.sh::7 - basename: [runWebScraping.sh]
2024-03-18 23:26:07.489 | INFO | runWebScraping.sh::7 - pwd : ['/Users/kevin/PycharmProjects/Projects2024/nov23_continu_mlops_meteo/src/data']
2024-03-18 23:26:12.814 | INFO     | __main__:<module>:128 - Lancement du script
2024-03-18 23:26:12.903 | INFO     | __main__:UpdateData:102 - Data is already up to date
2024-03-18 23:26:12.904 | INFO     | __main__:<module>:139 - Fin du script
2024-03-18 23:26:07.489 | INFO | runWebScraping.sh::7 - The script bash was successfully executed
```

Comment: you should try pointing explicitly to python3. ex: `/usr/local/bin/python3`

Comment: Please paste your script at [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: I've tried it .. It doesn't fix the issue

Comment: Yes, but the suggestions correct your faulty code. Without the quotation marks, several consecutive spaces are reduced to one.

Comment: @Cyrus Nothing wrong except adding quotes : /usr/bin/python3 "$SCRIPT_DIR"/webScraping.py >> "$PWD"/$LOG_FILE 2>&1

Comment: Check your cron logs.  Then add this to your cron line `>/tmp/out.txt 2>/tmp/err.txt` and review the messages there.  99% of the time, these are either directory locations errors, PATH values or environment.  cron does not run the script in the same environment you have in your bash.

Comment: @Nic3500 wen I check the system log file I got this   'Mar 19 10:08:44 MacBook-de-Kevin login[41784]: DEAD_PROCESS: 41784 ttys002
Mar 19 10:13:11 MacBook-de-Kevin syslogd[127]: ASL Sender Statistics
Mar 19 10:24:18 MacBook-de-Kevin syslogd[127]: ASL Sender Statistics
Mar 19 10:34:43 MacBook-de-Kevin syslogd[127]: ASL Sender Statistics
Mar 19 10:44:43 MacBook-de-Kevin syslogd[127]: ASL Sender Statistics
Mar 19 10:45:18 MacBook-de-Kevin login[47962]: USER_PROCESS: 47962 ttys002' There is no log related to cron ! is it normal ?

Comment: `man cron` will show you how to increase the log level.  And try the redirection I posted yesterday.  No logs == badly configured cron, never started.  Logs == look at that it did and figure out the issue.  You might need to add `-x` to your script's first line.

Comment: @Nic3500 I checked out.txt It's empty and err.txt has this error message  crontab: tmp/tmp.94636: Operation not permitted          I checked in google and what it supposed to be solution is to give Full Disk Access to Terminal. Now I don't got nothing in err.txt and same in out who supposed to shows logs from my webScraping.py .. Do you know what's the issue in this case ?